# Using token in page.tpl.php?

Tags: nodes, hooks, tokens

I downloaded the social media module and I found this token: [socialmedia:sm-twitter_username]. I want to show it where the *Read more* / *Add new comment* section is, under an article. Since I can't find a block that is for that sections how can I just insert it into the code?

Comment: Have you tried using token_replace()?

Answer (score 0):

The *Read more* link is added by [`node_build_content()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_build_content/7), while *Add new comment* is added by [`comment_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7); other links like those can be added by any module implementing [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

So, to answer your question, there aren't theme regions you could use to add links where you see *Add new comment*, and you don't add them in page.tpl.php. You need a module implementing `hook_node_view()`, for example using the following code.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $links['socialmedia_twitter'] = array(
    // Depending on what the token returns, you need to use one of these lines.
    'title' => token_replace(' [socialmedia:sm-twitter_username]'),
    'href' => token_replace(' [socialmedia:sm-twitter_username]'),

    'attributes' => array('title' => t("Read !username's latest blog entries.", array('!username' => format_username($node)))),
  );

  $node->content['links']['mymodule'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__node',
    '#links' => $links,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
  );
}
```

Rather than calling `token_replace()`, I would look at the module code, and see which function generates the token, and use it instead of calling `token_replace()`, since you are replacing a single, static, token you already know which one it is.
In any case, you need to check the code implemented by that module, as some token require an extra parameter passed as `$data`; without that, they don't work, or they don't produce the expected output.

In a theme, you would implement [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).